# How do I two merge several CSV files horizontally?

Tags: ruby, csv

I've got about 50 CSV files that need to be merged together horizontally into one CSV.

The headers can be ignored. A little bit simplified the files look like this:

File 1:

```
1,2,4,5,6
4,5,68,7,4,2
1,2

1,2,3
```

File 2:

```
1,2,4
4,5,6,4
3,4,5
3,4,5
```

The output should look like this:

```
1,2,4,5,6,1,2,4
4,5,68,7,4,2,4,5,6,4
1,2,3,4,5
3,4,5
1,2,3
```

The order of mergeing the files is also not important. I know how to merge them vertically, but I have no clue how to merge horizontally.
I thought about something like this with a nested array, but it does not work, but I don't know why. It seems like the data array does not accept the line array.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'csv'
data = Array.new
filecount=1
linecount=1

CSV.open("output.csv", "wb") do |output|
  Dir.glob('*.csv').each do |each|
    next if each == 'output.csv'
    file = CSV.read(each)
    file.each do |line|
      data[filecount][linecount] = line
      linecount=linecount+1
    end
    filecount=filecount+1
  end
end

puts data
```

Comment: Hmm, i should mention, that the files are very big. I wrote a bash script which does the work, but it is really slow. As the server has about 64GB of Ram it should be possible to load all of the file into memory.

Comment: I think you're on the right track with your  while loop idea. Why don't you try it out, then come back here with your results.

Comment: OK I added my idea. I can't get the lines in an array of arrays, that's my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prepared a small script that solves your problem, and added some comments for better explanation.

The main idea is to catch the input line by line so you do not have to use much memory.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'csv'

# map "treats" each element of the array with the block
files = Dir.glob('csv/*.csv').map { |file| CSV.open file, 'r' }

CSV.open("output.csv", "wb") do |out|
    loop do
        # shift returns the next line
        # compact remove nil entries
        line = files.map { |file| file.shift }.compact
        # remove entry if file has no row
        line.reject! { |e| e.empty? }
        # break the endless loop if no input to handle
        break if line.empty?
        out << line.flatten
    end
end
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll try to fully understand the code. Later I'll try to improve it for my needs.